# Bash script that removes part of a filename in every file under a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename

I have several files under a directory whose names are of the form `*.foo.bar`. I would like to write a bash script to rename each of these files by removing the `.foo` part.

For example, suppose that issuing `tree ~/dir/` returns

```
/home/user/dir/
|- george.foo.bar
|- john.foo.bar
|- paul.foo.bar
|- ringo.foo.bar
|- subdir
   |- jimmy.foo.bar
   |- robert.foo
```

Then running `script ~/foo/` should alter the contents of `~/foo` to

```
/home/user/dir/
|- george.bar
|- john.bar
|- paul.bar
|- ringo.bar
|- subdir
   |- jimmy.bar
   |- robert.foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion mechanism

```bash
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*foo.bar; do
    prefix="${file%.foo*}"
    suffix="${file##*.foo}"
    mv -v -- "$file" "$prefix$suffix"
done
```

The `${file%.foo*}` removes matching suffix (leaving only prefix), and `${file#*.foo}` removes prefix (leaving suffix). The double star glob (`**`) is needed to traverse all subdirectories and `setopt -s globstar` allows that glob.

Comment: This gives me the error `line 3: setopt: command not found`

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick It should be `shopt`, sorry, edited the answer (setopt is from zsh).

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick which `bash` version are you using? Also if you `ls **/*` which files are listed?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Would changing `**/*foo.bar` to `$1**/*foo.bar` allow me to use my desired directory as the first argument of the script?

Comment: If `$1` is a path then yes (don't forget about slash `/`).

Comment: Just one remark: if your file can contain two `.foo`s, like `bus.foo.baz.foo.bar`, then most probable double `##` is what you want, see edit.

Comment: For modern bash is enough `"${file//.foo/}"`. Other case `${file%.foo.bar}.bar` without `suffix` works too.

Answer (score 0):

To rename all files with `.foo.bar` to `.bar` in the current directory and its subdirectories:

```
rename 's/\.foo\.bar/\.bar/'  * */*
```

Here, `rename` is the rename utility from the perl package.  On some systems, it may be called `prename`.

(There is, unfortunately, also a `rename` executable that some systems have installed from the `util-linux` package.  It is *incompatible*.)